# Equivalent of ClassMapping<T>.Property() in FluentNHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've seen many examples of using `NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist.ClassMapping<T>` like so:

```
public class MyNhMap : ClassMapping<Entity>
{
    Property(a => a.Something, b => { b.Something(); });
}
```

What is the equivalent syntax in Fluent NHibernate with `FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap<T>`?

```
public class MyFnhMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    // ???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place, where you can compare both styles is here: [Mapping-by-Code - Property](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-property.html) *(see also section **Fluent NHibernate's equivalent**)*. An example of the fluent mapping *(a cite of an example from that link)*:

```
Map(x => x.Property, "columnName")
    .Default("defaultValue")
    .CustomSqlType("varchar(max)")
    .Length(SqlClientDriver.MaxSizeForLengthLimitedString + 1)
    .Not.Nullable()
    .Check("len(columnName) > 1")
    .Precision(2)
    .Scale(2)
    .Index("column_idx")
    .Unique()
    .UniqueKey("column_uniq")
    .CustomType<string>()
    .Update()
    .Insert()
    .Formula("arbitrary SQL expression")
    .Access.Field()
    // or .Access.Using<CustomAccessor>()
    .OptimisticLock()
    .Generated.Insert()
    .LazyLoad()
    .ReadOnly();
```

Comment: Yeah, I see...;) Enjoy NHibernate